# Powershell 1 liner to get and install product key

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Can I get and set the product key from bios in 1 line using cmd?

Currently I just use a batch file that contains

```
powershell.exe -c "(Get-WmiObject -query 'select * from SoftwareLicensingService').OA3xOriginalProductKey" | clip
```

To get the product key

How can I instead just straight up install the key to the bios.  Something like

```
powershell.exe -c "(Get-WmiObject -query 'select * from SoftwareLicensingService').OA3xOriginalProductKey" | slmgr
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you even try what you posted? Did you read the MS Docs on slmgr.vbs details to determine if it is designed to take piped input from some other script??

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

As we all know, slmgr is a .vbs that expect specific input, as defined in the [MS Docs on that VBS script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn502540(v=ws.11)).

That VBS file simply calls:
SoftwareLicensingService and SoftwareLicensingProduct WMI classes, which means you can code this out yourself. For example:

```
function Install-LicenseFile ($FilePath)
{
    $SoftwareLicensingService=Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingService -KeyOnly
    $FileContent=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($FilePath,[System.Text.Encoding]::Default)
    $SoftwareLicensingService | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName InstallLicense -Arguments @{License=$FileContent}
}
```

or this way...

> https://4sysops.com/archives/change-a-product-key-remotely-with-powershell

...or see this approach instead:

The PSSlmgr PowerShell module is intended to be a replacement of slmgr.vbs.

> https://github.com/it-praktyk/PSSlmgr